# DRY code in rescue => e in various model files in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, model, dry

In sidekiq_batch.rb,

```
def sidekiq_status
  begin
    something    
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error("\nRESCUENIL in sidekiq_status #{e.class} #{e.message} in #{e.backtrace}")
    # FIXME RESCUENIL
    nil
  end
end
```

In checkin.rb,

```
def attached_receipt_image
  begin
    something else
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error("\nRESCUENIL in attached_receipt_image #{e.class} #{e.message} in #{e.backtrace}")
    # FIXME RESCUENIL
    nil
  end
end
```

In barcode.rb,

```
def receipt_check?
  begin
    some code      
  rescue => e
    Rails.logger.error("\nRESCUENIL in receipt_check #{e.class} #{e.message} in #{e.backtrace}")
    # FIXME RESCUENIL
    nil
  end
end
```

Need to DRY up the code.  How can I write a common error-logging routine for all of these methods in my models?

Comment: Since the code in this question contains mostly placeholders, it is asking a how-to question rather than requesting a code review.

Answer (score 5):

You can write an abstraction for that, but you cannot `return` from there. You can write:

```
def with_log(name)
  begin
    yield
  rescue => exc
    Rails.logger.error("\nRESCUENIL in #{name} #{exc.class} #{exc.message} in #{exc.backtrace}")
    false
  end
end

with_log(:sidekiq_status) do
  something
  true # not needed if something returns a boolean with the success status
end or return
```

This `true` can also be moved to `with_log`, it depends on how you plan to use it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it is important to return nil because I have added the rescue log in place of rescue nil to fetch the backtrace in case of exception.

Comment: The proposed code is already returning `nil`, check that tail flow-control `or return`.

Comment: + 1 for using a monadic method. Also, this kind of code could actually belong to the logger itself. A [basic ruby logger](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html) already provides the `progname` option that more or less adresses this use case : `Rails.logger.error(:sidekiq){ "my message" }`. You can also provide your own message formatter, or even subclass `Logger` and replace rails' default one...